# Can we unblock the DuckDuckGo karma bot API access?

Tags: feature-request, api

DuckDuckGo serves up little karma badges like this:

[image: karma badge screenshot]
(in action: [my about page](http://alanhogan.com/about)).

However, apparently the karma data for StackOverflow is no longer grabbed (and will show up as 0 points if you attempt to use include it in the badge).

I know SO has its own badges, but there is value in one, uncluttered widget like this.

I spoke with Gabriel Weinberg (of DDG) and he said SO seems to be rejecting his bot’s attempts to grab the data, anymore.

Could we possibly un-block his bot?

Comment: Blah, wasn’t sure whether this is more a feature request, bug, or support item.

Comment: And unblocking it for all SE sites, as well as SE overall would be _great_.

Comment: Isn't the interesting question here *"Why was it blocked in the first place and has that situation been fixed?"*

Comment: @dmckee I suppose that is! I guess my head was all “solutions” more than “why,” really. But “why” is probably step 1…

Comment: I thought DuckDuckGo was a search engine. What's the point of all this "karma" nonsense? And why should we be supporting it?

Comment: @CodyGray It is a search engine, but what’s the harm? I think the intent was a combination of Gabriel wanting such a karma badge himself + thinking it might be a decent way to popularize DDG. (Hey, I thought Google was a search engine. What’s the point of this Google+ nonsense? `;)` )

Comment: Hmm, no answer has been submitted yet. Admins?